# IE crashing with a Runtime error while running javascript

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, runtime-error

IE is closing with the error window as shown below

[image]
<sub>(source: [tutorboy.com](http://tutorboy.com/error/IE_error.jpg))</sub>

In my web Application there is once mutil tab page having diffrecnt graph floating function with AJAX. This graph and tab were working in FireFox, but in IE when i click on the tab wil get this error. i checked with other pc also but.. the smae issue is there.....

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly are you running when this happens?

Comment: What's the Javascript? I'd check your Internet Explorer is well patched...

Comment: This looks more like a system error (e.g not really programming related).. Can you provide more info as to exactly what you were doing in Javascript?

Comment: Were you running a Crystal Report at this time?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886264 mentions that happening with the Excel 2002 web component, if you're using that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i got the solution :), i am using and IE PNG fix  for the Graph,.
and removed there is some div and image elements styles from the CSS file.

so beware of using IE tab function and style and PNG fix functions together...

thank you.

Comment: It should not be possible to encounter this error without a buggy browser extension (e.g. toolbar, BHO, or ActiveX control).